# Android app gradle " 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2' " issue

Tags: android

I have a problem with my app `gradle`, especially with `androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'`

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

I tried deleting it but then the `appcompact implementation` turned red

Comment: put your mouse above the red line and tell me what is saying

Comment: All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 27.1.0, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.0 and com.android.support:design:26.1.0

Answer (score 0):

just press ALT+ENTER (if you are in windows) or command + enter in mac and press the first hint that will pop up, this should automatically change your gradle version and then it should work

and prevent using .+ in your compiles, just place the number it should go, press alt + enter in those compiles too

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Base from your screenshot, delete your second constraint implementation 1.0.2 and update your appcompat, support and design to 27.1.1 and then sync.

If the appcompat turns red due to mixed version, I guess that is a bug in android studio because in my app it is also red but it runs smoothly.

Comment: The app works but it still red. i guess it kinda worked. thanks

Answer (score 0):

To migrate androidx. Go to **gradle Properties.** Copy and Paste this code

```
 android.useAndroidX=true
 # Automatically convert third-party libraries to use AndroidX
 android.enableJetifier=true
```

Now check **build gradle (Module :app)**. Add the line bellow in default Configuration

```
  testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

Now chage the implementation. If you already did just check for once. version might be different. Just update.

```
  implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
  implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
```

That's all. Hope it might help you to solve he problem.

**HappyCoding**